# Can not fetch values from remote spring config from spring boot client in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Here's my bootstrap.yml of my client

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      label: master

spring.application:
    name: microservices-client

spring.profiles:
    active: dev
```

Here's my spring config server bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservices-client

  profiles:
    active: dev

  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

And here's my spring config application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://git@riscm.company.com/sem/some_repo.git
          ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          privateKey:        | 
                             -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                             MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA3iOtvDLAez5Azk6fYt2ApS8smK3mGZVt9Uu/mqsZxijx9hEG
                             Q4oPHhebR1sX/AstBZAWvcx7O9fb7CfA1/Zsy3x520FbGAEH+rQtiVfafJ27ZfDm

                             xtiAKzX1bGWVV51WcgCF8A9NcXOqoIF6yXeyGgBmMwHG3vi/Yc0JzqLsqcqLdQ==
                             -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----


endpoints:
  health:
    sensitive: true

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  health:
    solr:
      enabled: false
```

When I run the config server locally I can pull values from spring boot client, but not when the server runs remotely as a docker image on Kubernetes.

I found one problem in client bootstrap.yml the label should be **master** and not **Master**!
I went ahead and deployed the microservices to Kubernetes and now I'm getting this error from the log client on Kubernetes. I'm not getting this error when I login directly into the client container.

```
2018-07-11 19:20:02.455  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888 
2018-07-11 19:20:02.545  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888 . Will be trying the next url if available
2018-07-11 19:20:02.545  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/microservices-client/dev/master":  Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-07-11 19:20:02.547  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.regen.rest.Application               : The following profiles are active: dev
```

.

Comment: 1. You don't need server bootstrap.yml - in your example it's almost the copy of client bootstrap.yml. But probably this is not the reason why it's not working
2. Is 8888 port exposed from your docker container ?

Comment: Yes. It's exposed. I'm able to hit it directly and correct data comes back for this call: http://192.168.99.100:8888/microservices-client/dev

Comment: Ok. Do you have some exceptions in microservices-client console ?

Comment: I've added the logs from both client and server, see above.

Comment: You are specifically telling the config client to look for config server at `http://localhost:8888`. That won't work.

Answer (score -2):

Please add bellow configuration to bootstrap.xml. I can fixed this issue by putting below configuration.

```
> spring:   cloud:
>     enabled: true
>     config:
>       uri: http://config-server:8888
>       failFast: true
>       retry:
>         maxAttempts: 20
```

Comment: I was able to solve this problem. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294653/can-not-connect-between-containers-within-one-pod-in-kubernetes